# Polybase converting sql to ansi sql for a sybase connection

Tags: sql, sybase, polybase

I have a polybase connection to a sybase server.

On my external tables I can not use the top command because poly-base converts it to limit

Example:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) *
FROM [polygrab].[dbo].[ExtEvent_test]
```

Cannot execute the query "Remote Query" against OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "(null)". 105082;Generic ODBC error: [SAP][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Syntax error near 'limit' on line 3  .

I also have this server as a linked server and the top commands are supported via SAOLEDB.17 provider.
However I can't figure out if this is the issue or how to change it.

My External Data connection is as follows:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [TicketMaster] WITH (
    LOCATION = N'odbc://externalserver.com:50459'
    , CONNECTION_OPTIONS = 'DRIVER={SQL Anywhere 17};
    Host=externalserver.com:50459; 
    Provider = ''SAOLEDB.17'';
    ServerName= <servername>;
    DatabaseName=<databasename>;'
    , CREDENTIAL = [PolyFriend2]
    )
```

Comment: Provider = ''SAOLEDB.17''; is useless as far as I can tell, I just added it for testing

Comment: Just for me to understand; your remote database is SAP's SQL Anywhere, and that database does not support the `LIMIT` syntax? What happens if you execute your statement from an application, i.e. not over PolyBase, does it work then? I am asking because you say that PolyBase converts the `TOP` to `LIMIT`, and I wonder whether that would not be related to the ODBC driver.

Comment: So I also connected the SAP SQL Anywhere as a linked server (using the same driver), in SSMS I can see the schema. I can also execute statements like `SELECT TOP 100 * FROM SAP.DB.SCHEMA.TABLE`. 

I put logging on the connection and I can see that when initialize they use different exes. When System DSN is used by linked server connection a sql exe is started and when polybase does it a special polybase sql connector is used. 

So the driver is currently working with more standard ODBC connection and not polybase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spoke to some Microsoft people working with the PolyBase feature.

When you create an external data source, by default `PUSHDOWN` is `ON`. The problem you run into is that the pushdown capability for generic ODBC data sources is in an early stage, and the generated SQL may not be in an expected dialect by the source. Which seems to be the case here.

So try an create the data source with `PUSHDOWN = OFF`, and see if it helps. Alternatively you can disable the pushdown in your query with an option: `OPTION (DISABLE EXTERNAL PUSHDOWN)`. So something like:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) *
FROM [polygrab].[dbo].[ExtEvent_test]
OPTION (DISABLE EXTERNAL PUSHDOWN);
```

Check and see whether this works.

Comment: this works, with pushdown being off it seems to work slower than linked server, but it works.

Comment: It is probably better to create the data source with `PUSHDOWN` `ON`, and use `OPTIONS` in your queries.